# jQuery Animations Control Sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm am attempting to build a homepage that has animations. I am having hard time controlling my animations though. All I need is to hide elements, and then show elements after a certain time. Loop through that sequence, and pause and show all elements when the someone hovers over the box. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MorganW09/GVhcM/) simple animation.

I have a long way to go. At first I tried using the .css() visibility property, now I'm using .show() and .hide().

I need a way to loop through my animations. I attempt to add another

```
setTimeout(clear1(), 3000);
```

to the end of my box1 function, but that wouldn't work for some reason.

I need a way to on a user hover over #box1, that all animations stop. I have tried using .clearQueue, but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: So you need to pause the animation when the user hovers over box one and restart the animation when the cursor exits box one?

Comment: Have you looked at the `stop` jQuery method? http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: I looked at that. I couldn't implement it correctly. It needs to both stop the animation and make sure all of the divs are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` and periodically call a function that increments (and resets) the box to display. Since I assign `setTimout` to `boxt`, I am able to call `clearTimeout(boxt)` on `box1`'s hover event so that I can stop specifically that loop. Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/GVhcM/3/). It might not be the exact effect you're trying to achieve, but it should be the right functionality and be easily adaptable with a few tweaks. Let me know if this works for you and if you have any questions about how it works :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, set to your css:

```
.box {display: none;}
```

**SHOW ALL BOXES ON HOVER** [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GVhcM/6/)

This will show all boxes on hover and then continue the animation from where it stopped (will hide the boxes that hadn't shown up during the animation). I think that is what you are after.

```
var index = 0; // To keep track of the last div showed during animation
var time_of_delay = 1000; // Set the time of delay

// Start the animation
$(document).ready(function () {
    box1(time_of_delay);
});

// The hover states
$("#box1_1").hover(
    function() {
        box1(0);
    }, function() {
        box1(time_of_delay);
    });

// The animation function
function box1 (delay_time) { 
    var time=delay_time;
    if(time>0) {
        $(".box").slice(index).each(function() {
            $(this).hide().delay(time).show(0);
            time=time+time_of_delay;
        });   
        index=0;
    } else {
        $(".box:visible").each(function() {
            index++;
        });
        $(".box").stop(true).show(0);
    }
}
```

**PAUSE ON HOVER** [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GVhcM/7/)

This will only pause the animation and continue from where it stopped.

```
var time_of_delay = 1000; // Set the time of delay

// Start the animation
$(document).ready(function () {
  box1(time_of_delay);
});

// The hover states
$("#box1_1").hover(
  function() {
    box1(0);
  }, function() {
    box1(time_of_delay);
});

// The animation function
function box1 (delay_time) { 
    var time=delay_time;
    if(time>0) {
        $(".box:hidden").each(function() {
          $(this).delay(time).show(0);
          time=time+time_of_delay;
        });
    } else {
        $(".box").stop(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
// hide all of the boxes
$('.box').hide();

// reference to each box, the current box in this list and a flag to stop the animation
var divs = box1.getElementsByClassName('box');
var i = 0;
var run = true;

// this will animate each box one after the other
function fade(){
    if(i < divs.length && run){
        $(divs[i++]).fadeIn(500, function(){
            setTimeout(fade, 1000);
        });
    }
};
fade();

// stop the above function from running when the mouse enters `box1`
$('#box1').on('mouseenter', function(){console.log('enter');
    run = false;
});

// start the function again from where we stopped it when the mouse leaves `box1`
$('#box1').on('mouseleave', function(){console.log('leave');
    run = true;
    fade();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/dKcn5/

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ibijiq/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
  var $box = $('#box1').find('.box'),
      boxN = $box.length,
      c = 0,
      intv;

  $box.eq(c).show(); // Show initially the '0' indexed .box (first one)

  function loop(){
    intv = setInterval(function(){
       $box.eq(++c%boxN).fadeTo(400,1).siblings().fadeTo(400,0);
    },1000);
  }
  loop(); // Start your loop

  $('#box1').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
    return e.type=='mouseenter' ? (clearInterval(intv))($box.fadeTo(400,1)) : loop();
  });
```

Where `++c%boxN` will take care to loop your animation using the Modulo `%` (reminder) operator inside a `setInterval`.
 Than all you need to do is to register a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` on the parent element to:

- clear the Interval on mouseenter + fade all your elements
- restart your `loop` function on mouseleave.